# Getting a mongo timeout error while inserting multiple records to a collection - Only happens when I use multithreading

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading

Objective - To create 50k-70k test data on a collection.

Implementation - The simple procedure(without threading) to create is slow as the dbs are on the server side. Hence we thought of creating multiple threads to create test data faster.

Code : ***InsertMany method:***
// I have got the authentication done for mongo client in the host uri itself, so it is not an issue

```
 public void insert(MongoClient client, List<Document> documents) {
            client.getDatabase(dbName)
                    .getCollection(collectionName)
                    .insertMany(documents);
        
}
```

**Multithreaded code :**
tempStudentBids is a list and has 20 records, so we are creating 20 threads

```
Runnable[] t = new Runnable[20];

        int i = 0;
        for(String tempStudentId : tempStudentBids) {
            t[i] = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mongoService.insert(mongoClient, documents);
                }
            };
         new Thread( t[i] ).start();
```

here is the error : Exception in thread "Thread-25" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOW
N, servers=[{address= {my-mongo-host}, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I not get the error and get insertion to work ?